# Split row into multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Current:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Amy | Adam | Bob| Cliff | Dave | David | Derek |...| Zachary
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a long row with around 300 names. Is there any formula/method that can split the row into multiple rows? I would like to have 10 entries on every row to make it easier to manage, example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Amy | Adam | Bob| Cliff | Dave | David | Derek | Diana |Elise| Eve |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Felix | Fiona | Ford | Gary |... | ... | ... |....|....|Luke|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|....|.....|.....|.....|.....|......|.....|....|Zachary|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Related [Google Spreadsheet partial row transpose and shift, partial row split](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102647/88163), [Split a column of strings with a single formula returning an array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88517/88163)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your row of 300 names starts in cell A1:

Insert this formula into cell A2:
`=INDEX($1:$1,INT(COLUMN()+(ROWS(A$2:A2)-1)*10))`

Drag the results shown in A2 across to J2.

Drag the resulting row down to row 31.

Example Sheet: [Google Sheets - Split row into multiple rows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQGTRfi1bNFGSttXRUGs5e9qf4TQWyuC6Dzn3GVNYgg/edit?usp=sharing)